# SELECT query in Hive to fetch data from a table as struct column

Tags: hive, bigdata

I'm trying to get data from a *Hive CTE* having normal columns in form of a **struct** column (data type), Also the 2nd value of the struct should be a ARRAY
Tried using **named struct** function,
When using ARRAY() function its throwing an error
*cannot recognize input near '('...*

table1 :

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 | 0.12 |
| 2 | 0.14 | 0.56 |
| 3 | 0.76 | 0.21 |

```
SELECT 
    id
    , named_struct(
          "key1", col1,
          "key2", ARRAY( col1, col2) ) as dummy_col
FROM table1
```

Comment: you have to provide sample data and output you get and your desired output

Comment: @eshirvana , have added the dummy data.

Comment: your query is working perfectly. what is your expected output ?

Comment: I'had made a syntax error, which was causing the issue, the above query is working fine. Thanks all for help :)